# Unity2D "Input.GetKeyDown isn't working anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am a beginner in both programming and game development in Unity so please have patience.

I am trying to add a force to the player upon the press of a button. The main concept behind this is that if the player is facing either left or right then the player should be launched in that direction.

I have been trying to make the code detect if the player is facing left or right depending on which button I pressed last ("A" or "D") using the "InputGetKeyDown(KeyCode.A/D) command.

I made two private bools (IsFacingRight and IsFacingLeft). IsFacingRight starts true by default and Left starts false but if the player switches direction then the bools would change accordingly. The launch would have happened when I pressed left-shift but that doesn't register either.

I tried using "Debug.Log" to see if the code detects the inputs and as I expected, it didn't. When I pressed "A" or "D" or "LeftShift" nothing would appear in the Debug console. So now I have confirmation that unity doesn't detect the inputs.

The code is a lot bigger but everything from it works expect the part that I will list below. I should also mention that the code doesn't get any errors and the simulation runs perfectly except for everything mentioned above. Here is the code:

```cs
    private bool IsFacingR = true;
    private bool IsFacingL = false;
    public Rigidbody2D RB;
    private float thrust = 20f;
    void Sliding()

    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            Debug.Log("Im R");
            IsFacingR = true;
            IsFacingL = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Debug.Log("Im L");
            IsFacingR = false;
            IsFacingL = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch")) ;
        {
            Slide();
        }
    }



    void Slide()
    {
        
        if (IsFacingR = true) ;
        {
            RB.AddForce(Vector2.right * thrust);
        }
        if (IsFacingL = true) ;
        {
            RB.AddForce(-Vector2.right * thrust);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add this to your monobehaviour;

```
void Update(){
    Sliding();
}
```

also you can handle isFacingL like this;

`private bool IsFacingL => !IsFacingR;`

Comment: The last part of your answer is not a good practice. In case the player can front/back face, you need to refactor much thing than if you handle left and right separatly.

Comment: I apologize again for my lack of knowledge to Unity and programming. Where exactly should i add that? I have read from another reply that i should replace void Sliding() with void Update() so is that what you are asking me to do?

Comment: Your class should extend MonoBehaviour class. You can add the Update function inside the class just like any other function. Make sure you add the class as a component in the editor.

Comment: The "public class Slide : MonoBehaviour" text was there since the beggining but i just didn't include the whole script. Also i included what you told me to, but  i have found out is that after i run the simulation both bools ("IsFacingR" and "IsFacingL") are set to true even if i mentioned in the script that IsFacingL starts false. another thing i noticed is that the bools dont change when i switch directions like it says in the script. What have i done wrong ?

Comment: can you remove semicolons after the if statements and try again. They shouldn't be there

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help so far. The Debug console started to work and the bools now change but there is one more issue. Whenever i press the "Crouch" button instead of applying the force, both bools change to true. My guess is that the forces to apply but because both bools are true the forces cancel each other out.

Answer (score 0):

You're not invoking `Sliding()` method.
Rename this method to `Update()`, make sure your class inherits MonoBehaviour and this class is on the active GameObject in the scene as Component.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you gave, the reason why `IsFacingR` and `IsFacingL` are never updated is because functions `Slide()` and `Sliding()` are never called.

If your class extends from `MonoBehaviour`, you can use the `Update()` function, which is called every frame.

```cs
void Update() {
    this.Sliding();
}
```